# MatLab: hist - fading colors depending on size

Tags: matlab, colors, histogram

Is it possible to have fading colors for the bars of an hist-plot just like for the hist3-plot (see screenshot below)?

[image: hist3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `hist3` with your 1D data with a twist :

```
y=randn(1,1e2);
bins = 10;
hist3([y(:) y(:)],[1 bins]);
view(90,0)
set(gcf,'renderer','opengl');
set(get(gca,'child'),'FaceColor','interp','CDataMode','auto');
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** To normalize the histogram, just rescale the labels according to `numel(y)`, this means to add the following line:

```
set(gca,'ZTickLabel',str2num(get(gca,'ZTickLabel'))/numel(y));
```

Comment: One more question: I need to normalize the histogram. I do this with:

 [f, x] = hist(y(:), bins);
        for i = 1:numel(f(1,:))
            for j = 1:numel(f(:,i))
                f(j,i) = f(j,i)/numel(y);
            end
        end
       bar3(x, f);

However, your solution does not work for bar3(). Is there a workaround?